# resetting usb bus to allow device mount after usbguard service stop

Tags: mount, usb, usbguard

in RHEL 8.9, there is a holdover problem with `usbguard`.  For example:

- usbguard active with `rules.conf` having just `allow with-interface one-of { 03:*:* 09:*:* }` to allow human interface devices (kybds/mice) and usb hubs
- I do `service usbguard stop`
- I **then** plug in a usb external disk, Apricorn, which has id 0984:1400 and would be `interface  { 08:06:50 }` *with 08 being mass storage devices*.
- even with usbguard service stopped, it appears that anything previously not whitelisted will not function

  - you could whitelist the new device, do `service usbguard start` followed by `service usbguard stop` and then that device will work.
  - this is problematic when I have multiple or new devices I want to use or test and don't want to make a mess of an existing rules.conf
  - i want things to operate like they would have prior to ever having started usbguard
  - i don't want to resort to a reboot to clear things if usbguard had been in effect and then I have some usbdevice problem where now knowing just stopping the usbguard service **doesn't really stop its effects.**

is there a linux command that will reset this usbguard effect?  causing a usb bus reset or something?

Comment: Does it work if you whitelist it and then restart the service?

Comment: Does it work if you whitelist it and then restart the service?   yes

Comment: Don’t you get a notification asking you whether to allow the device? You shouldn’t have to stop and start the service.

Comment: @ron If you want to stop ```usbguard``` from blocking usb devices while testing, try ```systemctl disable usbguard.service```  Or, is there a reason that you need it running while testing usb devices?

Comment: a `yum install usbguard` does not also install `usbguard-notifier`.  Once i installed `usbguard-notifier` the popup within the gnome desktop started happening saying *usbguard allowed* or *usbguard blocked*

Comment: @garnet : my point is once the service is running, even if you stop it usb devices will continue to be blocked if they did not match its previous rule set, only until after you reboot with the usbguard service disabled will everything not be blocked.  I do not know how else to explain it any different.  This being said, if you have issued with a usb device not working and you see the `usbguard.rpm` installed on the system then u have no way of knowing if that's the culprit until you reboot with it disabled or uninstalled.... or go modifying the usbguard rules.conf to allow it

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can get my usb disk to be mountable without having to reboot the system given what i've described?

As tested in the comments: add the device to the whitelist and restart the service.

Comment: I literally copied the question from your post and answered it (so I'm a bit surprised you say it's not what you asked!). Can you explain what is wrong about this approach? How does it not fit your needs?

Comment: you did not specify that in your question, so I'm now a bit surprised. Stopping usbguard doesn't leave your system in a dirty state – I'd say stopping to allow things is what should happen when you stop such a security service, right? Because that is *failing towards a safe state*, instead of *failing towards an unsafe state*. But why would you modify rules.conf? Isn't `usbguard allow-device` what you want in this situation to whitelist a device?

Comment: i reworded the question

Comment: thanks. Why do you stop usbguard then? that seems like plain the wrong thing to do! refer to the usbguard man page on how to control the run-time behaviour of usbguard.

Comment: you will have to explain why stopping the usbguard service is the wrong thing to do, and let me know what man page where explains how to control the runtime behavior.  I started a service, it was problematic, stopping it didn't stop the problems it was causing until I reboot with the service disabled, I don't know how else to say it.

Comment: You start a service to lock down your computer. So, instruct that service to change its behaviour instead of stopping it! That's what the `usbguard` tool is for, to communicate with the service about the rules you want. Hence, I recommended above to read the `usbguard` man page. You can open that using `man usbguard`.